# How should I restore an old build plate?

Tags: resin, repair

I have an Elegoo Saturn with a factory original built plate.

The plate was improperly cleaned and then left out. Causing a thin but uneven layer of cured resin to form on one corner. This effectively makes it impossible to level as one corner will always be a fraction of a MM out.

What is the best way to clean the resin off wile maintaining the surface?

Answer (score 1):

Removal of cured resin only works in mechanical ways, as the chemicals that can remove it are very aggressive and will eat at the base plate. Using a scraper or very sharp chisel to very carefully chip off the resin without scratching the surface is the *standard* solution.

If you damage the build plate, it can be re-ground, if you have food intact reference surfaces using a surface grinder.